# using gulp-ng-annotate with gulp-systemjs-builder

Tags: angularjs, systemjs, systemjs-builder

I have written my angularjs application in CJS format and using `gulp-systemjs-builder` to bundle them to one file.

I am trying to pipe the output to `gulp-ng-annotate` for DI but it fails because systemjs-builder inserts couple of line between the `\* @ngInject *\` and function declaration.

Example:

Before Bundle:

```
/* @ngInject */ 
function ReportCtrl($scope) {
    var _ctrl = this;
}
```

After Bundle:

```
/* @ngInject */ 
var global = this || self,
    GLOBAL = global;
function ReportCtrl($scope) {
    var _ctrl = this;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get over this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Instead of using comment `/* @ngInject */`, I had to use string `"ngInject";` as the first line after my function declaration. This way `gulp-systemjs-builder` didn't mess up the ordering and `ng-annotate` could successfully annotate the functions.

So instead of writing this -

```
/* @ngInject */ 
function ReportCtrl($scope) {
    var _ctrl = this;
}
```

I had to write this -

```
function ReportCtrl($scope) {
    "ngInject";
    var _ctrl = this;
}
```